# can I use RichEditBox for drawing purpose instead of Canvas in XAML/C# WinRT app

Tags: c#, xaml, drawing, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

Currently in WinRT canvas doesn't support rendering to image. Moreover it also doesn't support to write text onto it. So can I use RichEditBox instead of canvas ? As RichEditBox may contain drawing components, rich text and then I can save it.

I have made an application for [paint](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/416878/Metro-Paint). So I want to enhance it, so I am asking.

I tried this but it's also not working

```
<RichEditBox AcceptsReturn="True" x:Name="rbtMyRichTextBox">
    <Paragraph>
        <InlineUIContainer>
            <Rectangle Width="100" Height="100" Fill="Black"/>
        </InlineUIContainer>
    </Paragraph>
</RichEditBox>
```

I am getting this error

```
Cannot add content to an object of type "RichEditBox".
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is OK to turn the text into pixels you could use a [WriteableBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.aspx) for Metro. You allow the user to enter text and you render the textblock to the WriteableBitmap.

Unfortunately [it is not easy to render controls to bitmaps](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/65a6870d-1412-4701-ae12-258ed2b45452)

Rectangles in a RichEditBox are not XAML rectangles but are RTF rectangles. Search [the RTF specs](http://www.biblioscape.com/rtf15_spec.htm) for rectangle.